# replacing variable names with values

Tags: c#

I define a string with the following value:

```
var filterMe = "foo=1;bar=foo+5;foobar=foo+5-bar;";
```

And create an array which splits the string like so:

```
var splitter = filterMe.Split(';');

Dictionary<string,string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();

foreach (var split in splitter)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(split))
            {
                var part = split.Split('=');
                dictionary.Add(part[0], part[1]);
            }
        }
```

So the result of this "bar=foo+5" in dictionary is defined like this "bar","foo+5".

And now my question, how can I change the "foo" in the value "foo+5" to the key "foo" which contains the value "1" ? **The string filterMe will be longer and dynamic** so it will contain more than one variable (foo).

**Edit:** Since my question seems to be a little bit confusing, see below of how it should be replaced:

```
var foo=200;
var bar = foo+300;
```

The variable bar should then become:

```
var bar = 200+300;
```

Comment: `var output = filterMe.Replace("foo","myVar");`

Comment: @I4V But if you have variables like `foo`, `foo2`, `ifoo` it won't work correctly. He first has to tokenize, and then replace tokens.

Comment: int i =0;foreach (var split in splitter)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(split))
            {
                var part = split.Split('=');
                dictionary.Add(part[0].SubString(3) + i, part[1]); i++;
            }
        }

Comment: You should use a recursive method for that

Comment: It is not good way using recursive method.

Comment: doesn't he want to replace the "foo" with the value 1? None of these solutions will do that - they just split the string and allocate key-value -pairs from the tokenised string to the dictionary which is frankly the easy part

Answer (score 0):

This library seems to do what you need
http://csharpeval.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Usage&referringTitle=Home

after you do the split, go over each value in your dictionary , in order, and put the values (foo) as member of a temporary dynamic object (if you're using .net 4, if not as a dictionary).

then use the library to evaluate the second expression, store its result in the the temporary object/dictionary, and continue.

Answer (score 0):

You would need an array or Dictionary of your variables and their values (eg Foo, 5) as well. Split the string on the semi-colons (filterMe.Split(";") into an array to get the elements, then loop through and split the elements on the "=", using array[0] of the returned array as the key in the dictionary and array[1] as the value. 
Finally loop through the array of variables and values to replace the keys with their correct value. To perform the calculation (eg foo-5) I would create a `Func<string, string, int>` that accepts the 2 ints you want to perform the calculation on as strings from the dictionary, removes the operator, parses them as ints then uses the string of the operator to decide which operation (+, -, etc...) to perform, finally returning an int (or string I guess) of the calculated value

Answer (score 0):

The following test passes:
(No performance considerations taken **at all**)

```
[Test]
public void tst()
{
    var filterMe = "foo=1;bar=foo+5;foobar=foo+5-bar;";
    var dic = filterMe.Split(new[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                      .ToDictionary(x => x.Split('=')[0], x => x.Split('=')[1]);

    while (true)
    {
        var kvpToApply = dic.Keys
                            .Join(dic, x => true, y => true, (key, value) => new { key, value })
                            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.value.Value.Contains(x.key));
        if (kvpToApply != null)
        {
            dic[kvpToApply.value.Key] = kvpToApply.value.Value.Replace(kvpToApply.key, dic[kvpToApply.key]);
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    Assert.AreEqual("1", dic["foo"]);
    Assert.AreEqual("1+5", dic["bar"]);
    Assert.AreEqual("1+5-1+5", dic["foobar"]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
public enum ParserState
{
    ExpectSign = 0,
    ExpectValue = 1
}

public static void Parse()
{
    string filterMe = "foo=1;bar=foo+5;foobar=foo+5-bar;";

    var rows = filterMe.Split(new[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    Dictionary<string, int> locals = new Dictionary<string, int>();

    foreach (string split in rows)
    {
        var row = split.Split('=');

        if (row.Length != 2)
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }

        string name = row[0].Trim();
        string exp = row[1].Trim();

        if (!Regex.IsMatch(name, "^[A-Za-z_]+$"))
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }

        Regex rx = new Regex(@"\G(?:(?<local>[A-Za-z_]+)|(?<constant>[0-9]+)|(?<sign>[+-]))");

        var subExps = rx.Matches(exp).OfType<Match>().ToArray();

        if (subExps.Length == 0 || subExps[subExps.Length - 1].Index + subExps[subExps.Length - 1].Length != exp.Length)
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }

        int result = 0;

        ParserState state = ParserState.ExpectValue;
        string currentSign = "+";

        foreach (var subExp in subExps)
        {
            {
                Group sign = subExp.Groups["sign"];

                if (sign.Success)
                {
                    if (state != ParserState.ExpectSign)
                    {
                        throw new Exception();
                    }

                    currentSign = sign.ToString();

                    state = ParserState.ExpectValue;

                    continue;
                }
            }

            {
                Group local = subExp.Groups["local"];

                if (local.Success)
                {
                    if (state != ParserState.ExpectValue)
                    {
                        throw new Exception();
                    }

                    int value;

                    if (!locals.TryGetValue(local.ToString(), out value))
                    {
                        throw new Exception();
                    }

                    result = Operation(result, value, currentSign);

                    state = ParserState.ExpectSign;
                }
            }

            {
                Group constant = subExp.Groups["constant"];

                if (constant.Success)
                {
                    if (state != ParserState.ExpectValue)
                    {
                        throw new Exception();
                    }

                    int value = int.Parse(constant.ToString());

                    result = Operation(result, value, currentSign);

                    state = ParserState.ExpectSign;
                }
            }

            if (state != ParserState.ExpectSign)
            {
                throw new Exception();
            }
        }

        locals[name] = result;
    }
}

private static int Operation(int result, int value, string currentSign)
{
    if (currentSign == "+")
    {
        return result + value;
    }

    if (currentSign == "-")
    {
        return result - value;
    }

    throw new ArgumentException();
}
```

But be aware that if you want to introduce `()` or different priorities between operators (so that `1 * 2 + 3 == (1 * 2) + 3`) or signs for numbers (so `1 + -2`) or (`-2 + 1`) it becomes very difficult.

There are instruments/libraries for doing exactly this sort of things.

In the end it considers a "row" made in this format:

```
local = [local|constant]([+|-][local|constant])*
```